# Creating PDF Signature using ETSI_CADES_DETACHED subfilter results in invalid signature

Tags: java, pdfbox

I was trying out the example code include in Apache PDFBox under the package `org.apache.pdfbox.examples.signature` - in particular the `CreateSignature.java` - and was able to produce a valid signed PDF. That working code uses the adbe.pkcs7.detached signature type:

```
signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
```

But when I change this to using the ETSI.CAdES.detached signature type like so:

```
signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
```

The resulting PDF has an invalid signature according to Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, and it says: "The selected certificate has errors: Not valid for usage" in the Acrobat Reader's Certificate Viewer.

Is there something more to the code than just changing the subfilter to `PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED` in order to produce a valid signed PDF using PDFBox?

Comment: *"The selected certificate has errors: Not valid for usage" in the Acrobat Reader's Certificate Viewer."* - most likely this error message says it all: your certificate apparently is not valid for this usage. Legacy pdf signatures are quite lax as far as certificates are concerned, but pades has a number of requirements to the certificate. For more detailed analysis please share a signature illustrating the issue.

Comment: A sample invalid pdf signed using SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED can be downloaded from: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15z1v3VT0lpmn_hlWbKZXcQUCONTA_USa/view?usp=sharing

Comment: A sample valid pdf signed using SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED can be downloaded from: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Am09bA6VYdej6PLLFr7nr7klHBTf6vS9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The only difference in code when producing the two pdf files linked above, is just the specification of the subfilter used as described in my question.

Comment: Adobe says that your user certificate is not valid for usage. Probably it says so because of its *ExtendedKeyUsage* entry which contains one common usage for email signing, one Microsoft usage for document signing and one Adobe usage for document signing. Maybe Acrobat for PAdES signatures here only recognizes common entries, i.e. only email signing in your case, and by strict interpretation sees a mismatch here.

Comment: One real issue, though: Your CMS signature container does not contain an ESS signing-certificate or signing-certificate-v2 attribute. PAdES signatures require that attribute, though. Thus, your signature indeed is invalid. But if the error message observed was meant to indicate this issue, it is very poorly formulated.

Comment: I don't think it is an issue with the certificate that I am using. Because I am able to create a valid signed PDF if I used the same certificate with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC using the signature format "CAdES-Equivalent" in its settings for Default Signing Format. The problem I am facing is only with Apache PDFBox. Has anyone really tried to sign a PDF with Apache PDFBox using the SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED before?

Comment: Regarding the missing ESS signing-certificate attribute that is required by PAdES, I found this open ticket in PDFBox's Issues database requesting for the same thing: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5077.

Comment: Yes. But as mentioned above, if Adobe Acrobat fails validation only because of that attribute, the error message would be clearly misleading.